# Peltier Module constant time and thermal Load

Tags: semiconductors, physics, peltier, thermocouple

Hi everyone I am new to this forum.

I am doing a project where I need to control one of the sides temperature of a Peltier device against human skin. So one side is in contact with the skin, and the other with the heat sink.

I need the time constant of the Peltier module, and doing a lot of research I found that as soon as the power supply drives the device, it will settle to the desired temperature very quickly. Let´s say 1 sec (to achieve cold temperatures) to 3 seconds (hot temperatures). But this case is only when there's no thermal load. So this time will vary depending upon the temperature, mass, specific heat and other factors of the thermal load, which is skin in my case.

So I know the settling time required to achieve the desired temperature under no-load conditions of the Peltier device. Also I know how long the thermal load takes to acquire that temperature by thermal conduction. My question is:

Can I say that the **final settling time** of the **Peltier module** will be ts + tc? where ts = time constant of the skin, tc = time constant of the Peltier side under no-load conditions.

For example, a certain TEM can achieve a temperature of **10°C in 1.5** seconds on one of its sides. The skin is about 36°C and (doing quite roughly considerations) will acquire that temperature in **0.384 seconds**.

So the final settling time for that side of the Peltier device is **1.5 + 0.384 = 1.884 seconds**

Comment: Not sure how you computed that without thermal resistance, pressure, mass, surface area etc, for  dT/dt but seems too fast.  Because skin and flesh is a load.

Comment: I actually considered all those parameters.The example I gave above has not precise values, but the point here is how the heat transfer affects the other object.